# An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machin

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit against RabbitMQ. For the most part it works well, but after some time, the consumer starts throwing the an S-FAULT warning:

```
MassTransit.Messages Warning: 0 : S-FAULT rabbitmq://<redacted>/iemr_ExistingRowCheck 62560000-56b4-0050-b40b-08d69864ff75 ieMR.BulkCopy.MissingRowImport.Queues.ExistingRowCheck 
An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine, System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the
software in your host machine. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.Write(Byte[] buffer)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.Command.TransmitAsFrameSet(Int32 channelNumber, Connection connection)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SessionBase.Transmit(Command cmd)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.BasicPublish(String exchange, String routingKey, Boolean mandatory, IBasicProperties basicProperties, Byte[] body)
   at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Contexts.RabbitMqModelContext.PublishAsync(String exchange, String routingKey, Boolean mandatory, IBasicProperties basicProperties, Byte[] body)
   at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Contexts.RabbitMqModelContext.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.ModelContext.BasicPublishAsync>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Contexts.RabbitMqModelContext.<MassTransit-RabbitMqTransport-ModelContext-BasicPublishAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MassTransit.Internals.Extensions.TaskExtensions.<WithCancellation>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Transport.RabbitMqSendTransport.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`1.<<MassTransit-Transports-ISendTransport-Send>b__1>d.MoveNext()
```

Can I ignore these warnings?

I'm using MassTransit 5.3.1.0 with matching MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport against RabbitMq 3.7.5 on Erlang 20.3.

Comment: Is there something that the code is doing to trigger these?

Comment: I didn't see anything in the stack trace, but as part of the Consume task it will add jobs to another queue. Eg: 
```public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<TInOperation> context) 
context.Send(new MissingRow
                    {
                        TableName = op.TableName,
                        MissingRows = result
                    });
```

Comment: I'm also getting `The message was not confirmed: Unexpected Exception` errors, which in-turn throw `An error occurred trying to NACK a message with delivery tag 20: RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.AlreadyClosedException: Already closed: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by
Library` errors so I think I need to check the RabbitMQ logs.

Comment: Well, there is an issue with your RMQ. I'd start looking at the RMQ logs. It is not a MT issue.

Comment: It would be great to know what RabbitMQ logs at the same time.

Comment: Looks like RMQ was running our of memory:
```
2019-02-23 11:01:35.254 [info] <0.280.0> vm_memory_high_watermark set. Memory used:1724121088 allowed:1717798502
2019-02-23 11:01:35.254 [warning] <0.278.0> memory resource limit alarm set on node 'rabbit@THHS-D-RABTMQ01'.

**********************************************************
*** Publishers will be blocked until this alarm clears ***
**********************************************************
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions to check the RabbitMQ Logs.

The log was full of lines like the following:

```
2019-02-23 11:01:35.254 [info] <0.280.0> vm_memory_high_watermark set. Memory used:1724121088 allowed:1717798502
2019-02-23 11:01:35.254 [warning] <0.278.0> memory resource limit alarm set on node 'rabbit@THHS-D-RABTMQ01'.

**********************************************************
*** Publishers will be blocked until this alarm clears ***
**********************************************************
2019-02-23 11:02:22.596 [info] <0.280.0> vm_memory_high_watermark clear. Memory used:1714683904 allowed:1717798502
```

Increasing the memory high watermark in `rabbitmq.conf` seems to have done the trick:

```
vm_memory_high_watermark.relative = 0.8
```

I'll be asking the server team to increase the memory on this machine on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

I usually toss network errors on the server into the bitbucket.

This one means either the stateful firewall took out the (dead) connection or the IP address in the other end became unreachable in a way your host OS could fast detect.